# How can I make my quizbot ask another question if the answer before was correct?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I'm trying to make my discord bot ask another question if the previously answer was correct. I am currently trying it with a do while loop but I get in the infamous infinite loop and I can't find out for the life of me how to fix this. My code for this looks as followed:

```js
message.channel.send(question);
const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
const answer = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {maxMatches : 1, time: 10000, errors: ['time', 'maxMatches']})
const ANS = answer.first();

if (ANS.content.toLowerCase() === correctAnswer.toLowerCase()){
    do {
        var question = randomQuestion.question;
        message.channel.send(question);
    } while(ANS.content.toLowerCase() === correctAnswer.toLowerCase());

// message.channel.send("hell yeah.");
} else {
    message.channel.send("Nah.");
}
```

Comment: In your loop you do not change the ```ans``` object. You have to read the answer first before you can decide if you want to change the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you change the a piece of the loop condition for each iteration.

```js
const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;

const listenForAnswer = async () => {
  return (await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
    maxMatches: 1,
    time: 10000,
    errors: ['time', 'maxMatches']
  })).first();
};

const askQuestion = async () => {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*data.results.length);
  const question = data.results[randomNumber].question;

  message.channel.send(question);

  let answer = await listenForAnswer();
    
  while (answer.content.toLowerCase() !== correctAnswer.toLowerCase()) {
    message.channel.send("Nah.");   
    answer = await listenForAnswer();
  }
  
  // We've made it out of the incorrect loop...
  message.channel.send("hell yeah.");
};

while(true) {
  // Ask questions forever...
  await askQuestion();
}
```

This example has not been tested. I just threw it together based on assumptions I made from the code provided in your question.

Comment: It got me out of the incorrect loop! Thank you. Now I just have to figure out how to change the question. Currently it runs the same question again and again! But I can figure that one out on my own. Again thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it helped. If you want to edit your question with your current `getRandomQuestion()` routine, we can possibly take a look and figure out the issue.

Comment: I have no idea if I'm allowed to change your code snippet but I just added the things I was missing and it now works as intended. Thank you for offering your help again!